# How to retrieve value from sql scalar function using c#

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to pass paramtere to sql scalar function which will return me one value that i want to show.

`GetValue` is a sql scalar function

```
private int GetNewValue()
        {
    int Value = 0;
                string connectionString GetConfigurationSettingValue("ConnectionString");
                int Days = 20;

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetValue", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Time", Days));

                        Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    }
                }

                    return  (Value);
```

But i'm unable to get value from Sql Scalar function nor getting any error

Is there i'm missing something ?

Comment: "Is there i'm missing something ?" - a description of the error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error but I'm also not getting a returned value from my Scalar function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat your scalar function like a stored procedure, and I'd also recommend to **always** use the schema prefix - for functions it's doubly important! Use `dbo.GetValue` - not just `GetValue`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("-your-conn-string-here-"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetValue", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Days;

    // define a return value from the stored function
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    // set type to be a stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // open connection, execute non query        
    conn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // the return value parameter now contains the result 
    object returnValue = cmd.Parameters["@return"].Value;

    // close connection
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1. I wondered why the OP had code that used CommandType.Text;
 !